# Minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{3}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, nested-radicals

Let $a=\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{3}}$. Then
\begin{align*}
&a=\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{3}}\\
&\implies a^2=3+2\sqrt{3}\\
&\implies a^2-3 = 2\sqrt{3}\\
&\implies (a^2-3)^2 = 4\cdot 3=12\\
&\implies (a^2-3)^2-12=0.
\end{align*}

So, $a$ a root of
$$(x^2-3)^2-12=x^4-6x^2-3.$$

By Eisenstein's criterion, $x^4-6x^2-3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$. So, $a$ is algebraic of degree $4$.

---

However, I've seen that the degree of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{3}})$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $2$.

**What is wrong with my attempt?**

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. The polynomial is indeed irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. What makes you think the degree should be $2$ anyway?

Comment: If the degree was $2$, as $\sqrt3\in\Bbb Q(a)$, we would have $\Bbb Q(a)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt3)$. Can we have $(r+s\sqrt3)^2 =3+2\sqrt3$ for some rational $r,s$?

Comment: W|A agrees with your minimum polynomial.

Comment: Where did you see that the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3 + 2 \sqrt 3})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $2$? Can you give the full quotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unquestionably right. A *much* more advanced viewpoint:

The ring $R=\Bbb Z[\sqrt3\,]$ is the integer-ring of the quadratic number field $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt3\,)$. It’s “well known” (and easy to prove) that $R$ is a Principal Ideal Domain (class number is $1$).

We have the factorization $z=3+2\sqrt3=\sqrt3(2+\sqrt3\,)$, in which the two factors are respectively, an indecomposable element, and a generator of the (free part of the) unit group. In particular, neither is a square, and they are independent modulo squares. Therefore, the square root $\sqrt z$ generates a quadratic extension of $K$. That does it.

Comment: I'm confused. Maybe because I'm missing a lot of important background. If $\sqrt z$ is of degree $4$, on account of having minimal polynomial $x^4 + a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt z)$ contains $\sqrt z$, doesn't that mean that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt z)$ is of degree $4$, not degree $2$?

Comment: Right you are: $\Bbb Q(\sqrt z\,)$ is quadratic over $K$ and quartic over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are right.

Another way:
$$\sqrt{3+2\sqrt3}=\sqrt[4]3\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}=\frac{\sqrt[4]3}{\sqrt2}\sqrt{4+2\sqrt3}=$$ $$=\frac{\sqrt[4]3}{\sqrt2}\sqrt{(1+\sqrt3)^2}=\frac{\sqrt[4]3}{\sqrt2}(1+\sqrt3),$$ which gives the same answer.

Comment: I probably missed something, but exactly how does this help in finding the minimal polynomial? If anything, this suggests that we would need to include both the fourth root of three and the square root of two. Those generate a degree eight extension field. Undoubtedly there is a way of getting to the minimal polynomial from here also, but instead of squaring twice you need something else to get rid of the radicals.